# How to get the pid of process using python

Tags: python, process, pid, psutil

I have a task list file which is having `firefox , atom , gnome-shell`

My code

```
import psutil
with open('tasklist', 'r') as task:
    x = task.read()
    print (x)

print ([p.info for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']) if x in p.info['name']])
```

Desired out

```
[{'pid': 413, 'name': 'firefox'}]
[{'pid': 8416, 'name': 'atom'}]
[{'pid': 2322, 'name': 'gnome-shell'}]
```

Comment: And the actual output is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

similar to the answers above, but from the question it seems you are only interested in a subset of all running tasks (e.g. firefox, atom and gnome-shell)

you can put the tasks you are interested in into a list..then loop through all of the processes, only appending the ones matching your list to the final output, like so:

```
import psutil

tasklist=['firefox','atom','gnome-shell']
out=[]

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if any(task in proc.name() for task in tasklist):
        out.append([{'pid' : proc.pid, 'name' : proc.name()}])
```

this will give you your desired output of a list of lists, where each list has a dictionary with the pid and name keys...you can tweak the output to be whatever format you like however

the exact output you requested can be obtained by:

```
for o in out[:]:
    print(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import wmi  # pip install wmi

c = wmi.WMI()
tasklist = []

for process in c.Win32_Process():
    tasklist.append({'pid': process.ProcessId, 'name': process.Name})
print(tasklist)
```

For Unix:

```
import psutil

tasklist = []

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        tasklist.append({'pid': proc.name(), 'name': proc.pid})
    except:
        pass
print(tasklist)
```

Comment: It looks like OP is using Linux, judging by a presence of `gnome-shell` process.

Comment: @crayxt think you are right. updated the answer for both cases! :)